# How do I prove that my piecewise function is bijective

Tags: proof-writing, cardinals

***Question***

> Prove that the set $$\mathbb{N} \text{ and } S = {x\in \mathbb{R}|x^{2} \in \mathbb{N}}$$ have the same cardinality.

I drew an arrow diagram, and got this equation:

$$ f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow S $$
$$
f(x) =
\left\{\begin{matrix}
\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{2}} & \text{when x is odd}\\ 
-\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}} &  \text{when x is even}
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
Now, I need to prove the bijection of this piecewise function. I get stuck on that.

***What I tried:***

I know that in order to prove bijection, I need to prove injection & surjection.

*Injection:*
Let $$ f(x_1) = f(x_2) \Rightarrow x_1 = x_2 $$

Now from here, I get stuck in proving $$x_1 = x_2$$

*Surjection:*

I know I have to try and find the inverse of the equation and prove that $$ y = f(x) $$, but again, with the piecewise, I am stuck.

---

Incase the LATEX formatting for the piecewise doesn't work (I spent 10 mins trying to make it work), here is a gif
[image: piecewise question]

Comment: I mean, what is the set $S$ if you are trying to prove it is bijective you need to know what $S$ is, but every function is surjective onto its image, so if you just say $S$ is the image, then it is automatically surjective, so then you are left with injectivity

Comment: Sorry, I submitted the post too early by accident. I updated the post with more info,

Comment: You don't need a formula for the inverse to prove the function is injective. You can argue by cases that parallel the definition of the function. Words are just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things to observe about your function:

1. If $f(n)>0$, then $n$ is odd
2. If $f(n)<0$, then $n$ is even
3. If $f(n)=0$, then $n=0$ (this is actually if and only if)

For injectivity, your attempt is just saying the definition of injective, that is a good start, but let's think about what that means. Say we have that $f(n)=f(m)$. Then there are three cases:

1. $f(n)=f(m)>0$, then we know that $n$ and $m$ are both odd, say $n=2k+1$ and $m=2l+1$, and we know that $f(n)=f(2k+1)=\sqrt{\frac{2k+2}{2}}$ and $f(m)=f(2l+1)=\sqrt{\frac{2l+2}{2}}$, so you should have that since $f(m)=f(n)$ that $\sqrt{\frac{2k+2}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{2l+2}{2}}$, you can use this to show that $k=l$, and then conclude $n=m$.
2. If $f(n)=f(m)<0$, you can do a similar analysis, but say $n$ and $m$ are even.
3. If $f(n)=f(m)=0$, then by the note you know $m=n=0$ (you might also want to prove this)

Now for surjectivity. Say you have some $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2=n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Again, there will be $3$ cases

1. If $x>0$, then look at $2n-1$ which is odd, so $f(2n-1)=\sqrt{\frac{2n-1+1}{2}}=\sqrt{n}=x$ (this gives surjectivity to the positives)
2. If $x<0$ see if you can do a similar argument to get the negatives.
3. If $x=0$ just take $n=0$ (note I assume you include $0\in\mathbb{N}$)

Comment: Note: at the end I said I made the assumption that you include $0\in\mathbb{N}$, but come to think of it even if you don't, then the above should still hold because then $0\notin S$ as $0^2=0\notin\mathbb{N}$